# Способы хранения картинок

Tags: веб-программирование

День добрый, добрые люди.
Скоро вот собираюсь заняться с одним проектом. Естественно, там будут картинки )).
Хотелось бы узнать ваши мнения насчет хранения картинок. Обычно их бросаю в папку img.
Но один знакомый сказал, что лучше хранить их в базе, в виде base64. Понимаю, что если хранить в таблице, то скорость то снизиться все таки, 1 картинка = 1 запрос.

А Вы , как думаете?

Comment: Убрал лишние метки, ибо мусор. Из вопроса неясно, чем являются изображения - данными или оформлением. В последнем случае - совет глупейший.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ИМХО хранить картинки в БД огромная глупость! Вырастет число запросов к БД,в десятки раз увеличится вес самой БД. И если вы планируете отображать картинки типа src="data:image/gif;base64,КОД_КАРТИНКИ" то многократно увеличите вес самой странички, при этом пользователь даже отключив загрузку картинок в браузере будет вынужден тратить свой трафик (Где нить в дороге на GPRS этот вопрос по сей день актуален) на загрузку кода картинок, ну и поисковикам само собой придется разгребать лишний мусор чтобы добраться до полезного содержания.
ИМХО Вся графика должна хранится на диске, рассортированная по папкам, в редких случаях можно вставлять base64 код в стили и скрипты.

Comment: Большая БД или высоконагруженная ничем плохим не является. Базы данных, собственно, и предназначены для того, чтобы данные хранить и обрабатывать запросы. Если данные полезные и запросы обоснованы и оптимизированы — значит БД делает свое дело, и это хорошо. Другое дело, что хранить данные «за тридевять земель» и платить расходы по их постоянной доставке — сомнительное удовольствие.

Comment: Ну так ведь никто не мешает кэшировать данные в том числе и картинки из базы... Синхронизация файловой структуры и базы, где идут ссылки на пути к файлам бывает довольно неприятной задачей.

Comment: @Павел Вершивин , согласен. Тогда буду как обычно бросать файлы в img )))

Answer (score 3):

Если есть потребность максимально уменьшить возможность подмены картинок - то хранение в базе предпочтительнее.

Answer (score 2):

В базе, да еще и в base64 глупость несусветная. В базе хранить надо пути до файлов.

Comment: Не скажете, а как быть с формулами, типа Microsoft Equation? В картинках или в базе (если честно незнаю в каком формате) хранить?

Comment: А в интернетах есть только jpg,png,gif.. Никто не знает о Microsoft Equation, поэтому логично будет делать из этого картинки и хранить в базе пути до них)

Comment: Посмотрите http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax. Или сюда http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wp/  Ещё есть svg math (для тех браузеров, которые понимают)

Comment: мне нужен какой то общий способ хранения картинок, формул - или в базе, или же в папках. Что скажете? Нужен оптимальный вариант

Comment: Хранение формул в картинках -- плохая идея. Используйте уже посоветованный MathJax, или еще что-то вроде него

Comment: В базу можно положить OLE объект - тот же Microsoft Equation

Comment: "глупость несусветная" 1) это ваше ЛИЧНОЕ мнение, 2) это зависит от специфики DDD.

Answer (score 2):

Если уж хранить картинки в БД то лучшего способа чем хранить их в виде `BLOB` полей нет. Посему хранить в виде Base64 - глупость. Некоторые БД поддерживают специальный тип поля `IMAGE`, ну уж `BLOB` то все базы поддерживают!

С точки зрения быстродействия, показ картинки из файловой системы конечно будет быстрее + опять же проще организовать кэширование, редактирование и проч. фичи.

Answer (score 2):

Ваш знакомый знает толк в извращениях, в base64 кодировать и декодировать потом на каждый чих. Лучше бы мне это процессорное время подарил.

Давайте рассмотрим плюсы и минусы хранения ассетов (графики, скриптов, стилей) в БД, по сравнению с файлами на диске:

Плюсы:

1. Доступность из любого места проекта, без проксирования и использования сетевых файловых систем;
2. Возможность гарантированного хранения произвольных метаданных, без отрыва от файла;
3. Возможность организации файловой системы не в виде орграфа.
4. Пониженная нагрузка на физические диски (без учета возможного локального дискового кэша);
5. ACID, при условии реализации его базой данных.

Минусы:

1. Дополнительная машинерия для доступа к данным (отдачи клиенту, записи файлов администратором и т. д.);
2. Повышенная латентность, нагрузка на сеть и сервер БД;
3. Избыточная обработка, связанная с протоколом работы с БД (включая сериализацию данных), по сравнению с протоколом работы с файловой системой.
4. Отсутствие некоторых инструментов, например, [`sendfile(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile) или [`mmap(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap).

В абсолютном большинстве случаев, хранение и отдача ассетов сводится к неизменяемым файлам с хорошо определенными именами, прекрасно укладывающимся даже не в орграф, а в дерево. Отдача легковесным сервером типа nginx, за счет инструментов типа `sendfile` и кэширования (выполняется VFS-подсистемой ядра ОС), позволяет отдавать их с минимальными издержками, что и требуется для задачи.

Большинство плюсов, при этом, достаточно условны, т.к. БД в большом ряде случаев будут проигрывать по сравнению с более специализированными инструментами (например, GlusterFS или MooseFS) или композитными (БД для метаданных, традиционная ФС для данных) решениями.

Итого: следует считать, смысла в базе данных для хранения ассетов нет. Если возникает редкий случай, когда он появляется — вы об этом узнаете.

Comment: спасибо за детальную инфу.

Answer (score 0):

имхо хранение картинок в субд нужно только в специализированых случаях, напр: хранение сканов докуметов или еще что-то в таком роде.

есть смысл обычные картинки держать просто на локальной файловой системе, если проэкт розростется то легко можно перенести статику (images, js, css) на отдельный веб сервер