# Чем лучше отображать картинки из BLOB поля

Tags: php

В общем в данный момент на чистом php читаются данные из базы данных и генерируется html страничка с таблицей.
В таблице есть BLOB поле с картинкой для каждой строки, она будет отображаться в всплывающей подсказке при движении мыши над таблицей и на каждой строке меняться. Естественно все грузить не вариант думаю, надо подгружать по мере надобности? **С помощью чего это лучше осуществить?** (я так понимаю просто html тут уже не хватит, может ли с этим справится js или какие технологии используются для таких динамических целей?)
И к таблице хотелось бы сделать, в будующем, фильтр по всем полям...

PS: Поправьте вопрос, я не знаю как сформулировать его точнее

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/112738/186083

Comment: @Visman, согласен. Но мне всё таки интересно посмотреть что можно "выжать" при таком подходе. Допустим оно будет работать локально и о траффике мы не думаем. На сколько "дружелюбно" это будет выглядеть при загрузке из базы или будут сильные глюки и с этим ничего не поделать? Мне просто удобнее всё иметь в одном файле.

Comment: Храню картинки в базе - проблем не наблюдал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пишете какой-то такой скрипт

```
// image.php

function process(): bool {
  $id = $_GET['id'] ?? '';
  if (!is_numeric($id))
    return false;
  $sql = <<<'SQL'
    SELECT
      ph.`photo`,
      typ.`name`
    FROM
      `photos` ph
      LEFT JOIN `mime_types` typ ON (
        ph.`mime_type_id` = typ.`id`
      )
    WHERE
      ph.`id` = ?
SQL
    ;
  }
  $db = new db();
  $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
  $photo = '';
  $mime = '';
  $stmt->bind_result($photo, $mime);
  $stmt->execute();
  if (!$stmt->fetch())
    return false;
  header('Cache-Control: public');
  header(sprintf('Content-type: %s', $mime));
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($photo));
  echo $photo;
  return true;
}

if (!process()) 
  header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 400 Bad Request');
```

При движении мышей показываете

```
<img src="image.php?id=XXX" />
```

где вместо `XXX` id нужной Вам картинки.

Само собой показываете не сразу при движении мыши, а с задержкой, на тот случай, если пользователь передумает и уберет мышь

Comment: Эдак и БД сервер можно без проблем перегрузить создав простенький скрипт для перебора ID от нуля до ~...

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, А ведь точно, img же может отдельный php выдавать... Что-то я в этом направлении не подумал даже. Всё гениальное - просто! Спасибо, как попробую, отпишусь)

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov, в моём случае не актуально, но увидеть ваше предложение в учётом данного замечания было бы не лишним)

Comment: Если все же нужно хранить ихображения в БД, тогда можно сделать индетификатор изображения не просто integer, а uuid. В примере выше обезопасит от перебора по id+1. И использовать кэш запроса БД. Но при хранении изображений в БД, её размер будет очень сильно расти

Comment: @RaZik размер не страшно. У меня там 200 записей и раза в два больше станет очень не скоро... К каждой записи будет 2-3 картинки... Не смертельно! На счёт "использовать кеш запроса" можно подробнее?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, отлично работает, спасибо!